# converting complex ffmpeg command to python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, ffmpeg, pip

I have a complicated `ffmpeg` command that takes audio and image as input, and exports a music video.

```sh
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 2 -i "front.png" -i "testWAVfile.wav" \
    -vf "scale=2*trunc(iw/2):2*trunc(ih/2),setsar=1,format=yuv420p" \
    -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune stillimage \
    -crf 18 -c:a aac -shortest -vf scale=1920:1080  "outputVideo.mp4"
```

I'm trying to write a python3 program `cmdMusicVideo.py` which will run this command in pure Python. I know that to run this command you need the `ffmpeg` program, I'm trying to write it in pure python3, where I'm not just spawning a separate process to run the bash command where the user needs to have `ffmpeg` installed.

I've looked at the various solutions to running `ffmpeg` in python3, and they're either:

- A:  Just running the `ffmpeg` command as a subprocess, where the user needs to have `ffmpeg` installed
- or B: An ffmpeg pip program like `ffmpeg-python`

The pip libraries I've checkout out all use incredibly different formatting, and I haven't found a way to replicate my `ffmpeg` command. I've searched the `loop` command in their python package documentation and it doesn't appear anywhere.

Is there a way to convert my `ffmpeg` command into a python3 program where the user doesn't need to already have `ffmpeg` installed on their computer?

The plan is to eventually turn this into its own pip package, and my concern is that if I use the **A** method, there would be a case where somebody tries to run my pip command but doesn't have `ffmpeg` installed on their terminal (maybe using a python3 specific terminal?)

Comment: This is probably too broad. There are many `pip` packages which depend on external utilities or libraries; you should just figure out how to make sure that `pip` knows how to install the prerequisites or display a useful error message.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a pure Python package for video processing at all. Most of the packages use fast, proven non-Python libraries in the background (ffmpeg, vlc, opencv).

Comment: `ffmpeg-python` doesn't even use libraries — it runs `ffmpeg` as a subprocess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert my ffmpeg command into a python3 program where the user doesn't need to already have ffmpeg installed on their computer?

Short answer: no.

> The plan is to eventually turn this into its own pip package, and my concern is that if I use the A method, there would be a case where somebody tries to run my pip command but doesn't have ffmpeg installed on their terminal (maybe using a python3 specific terminal?)

You should add a check during the installation step to ensure the user/system has an `ffmpeg` binary on their path, and raise an error if not (and point the user to a URL with ffmpeg install instructions). There isn't a "best" way to do this, it depends on how you are having the user install the program. Here are three options.

#### Makefile

If you're using a Makefile, you can add something like this to the top of the Makefile:

```
ifeq ($(shell which ffmpeg),)
$(error Please install ffmpeg using "apt-get install ffmpeg")
endif
```

This will fail before any `make` commands are run if the `ffmpeg` binary is not installed.

#### setup.py only

If you're just using a `setup.py` file alone with no Makefile, you can add something like this to the top of your `setup.py` (before you call `setup()`):

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.run(["ffmpeg","--help"], check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    print('Please install ffmpeg using "apt-get install ffmpeg"')
```

#### conda

This is actually one of the use cases of conda, which is intended to give users an easy tool for installing things (like pip), but also be able to build and install non-Python binaries (unlike pip). You can see that ffmpeg is available through conda:

```
$ conda search ffmpeg
Loading channels: done
# Name                       Version           Build  Channel
ffmpeg                           3.4      h766ddd1_0  pkgs/main
ffmpeg                           3.4      h8a2ae75_0  pkgs/main
ffmpeg                           4.0      h01ea3c9_0  pkgs/main
ffmpeg                           4.0      hc84425e_0  pkgs/main
ffmpeg                           4.2      h677a3f5_0  pkgs/main
```

so instead of packaging your program and making it available on Pypi, you could create a conda recipe instead. See [creating conda recipes](https://conda-forge.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipe.html) for details, but basically you would specify ffmpeg as a requirement in your `meta.yml` file:

```
requirements:
  host:
    - ffmpeg 4.2.*
```